# Using active records in Ruby on rails to perform sql operation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models A & B. In table A, I have three columns A1, A2 and A3. In table B, I have three columns as well B1,B2 and B3. 
When my controller for A updates its table, I want to pass an id, which can be used by controller B to update its table, with a sql statement which should be like:

```
UPDATE TABLE B SET B2 = some_value WHERE B1=param_value AND B2=NULL
```

I need specifically B2 to be null or empty, there are multiple entries in table B with `B1=param_value`, but only one row can with `B1=param_value` can have B2 empty.

I have kept this function in my application_controller.rb file

```
def update_tableB(id)
   temp = B.find_by_B1(id).find_by_B2(null)
   # Not sure how to set temp.B2 to some value I want
   B.update(temp).find_by_B1(id).find_by_B2(null)
end
```

Comment: this is really difficult to read those abstract table and column names, please consider to use real names to make question more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ActiveRecord you work with models that map your objects, you don't work with tables directly. Therefore, assuming B is a model, your SQL update query is performed as it follows

```
Model.where(b1: param_value, b2: nil).update_all(b2: some_value)
```

I can't be more specific as your question is too abstract.